# Entity Framework - Trouble with one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, virtual, one-to-many

We are making a code-first approach, and are having trouble with a one-to-many relationship.

- A Departement (Dep) has a list of Employees.
- Each Employee belongs to a Dep. (Required)
- I want to update the Employees name. (Without touching the Dep)

I have reduced the sample to some simple classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Dep dep { get; set; }

}

public class Dep
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Adding new values works fine like this:

```
Dep dep = new Dep { name = "My Departement" };
Employee employee = new Employee { name = "My name" };
dep.Employees.Add(employee);

context.Deps.Add(dep);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, if we want to update an Employee, we run into trouble.

```
// Get Employee by Id
Employee employee = Repository.Employees.Single(p => p.Id ==<some id>);
employee.name = "My new name";
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Question 1:**

If we use

- public virtual Dep dep { get; set; }

as in the code above, we notice that the Dep object is available from the Employee when debugging. And the Dep is loaded fine when we browse the object.

But if we remove virtual from the Employee-class like this:

- public Dep dep { get; set; }

, then Dep is always null. STRANGE!

Why is this happening? Isn't virtual just to decide if the related data should be lazy-loaded or not?

**Question 2**

Since we want to use virtual anyway, the trouble start with saving the updated Employee. It always fail with the message that Dep is required. The Employee already have a Dep, and i don't want to mess with it. I only want to change the name of the Employee. Nothing else...

Why is it loosing the Dep relation when saving the Employee?

I can make it work when using virtual, and if I make sure the Dep also is loaded manually by

1. adding some code to read some value in the Dep object

or

2. Debugging, and browsing the Dep object

But is all that really necesessary? I really don't care about the Dep relation in this context. Why should I have to load the Dep-data?

Comment: You'll have to clarify the second situation. What code makes it work? Are you still using `virtual` then?

Comment: Q1: How should `Dep` be loaded when it can't be lazy loaded - without virtual - and you don't `Include` it? It is expected to be null.

Comment: It works if I use virtual, and include a line of code like this: int id = employee.dep.Id; This loads the Dep, and then the save of Employee is OK.

Comment: have you tryed this: `context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

Comment: @FrodeAntonsen It's better to ask one question per post. I think Question 2 is the main question. As you see, tschmit007 found the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 2:

this is because you use the [Required] attribute. In this case you ask to the framework (not only EF) to handle the required constraint.

If you want to apply the constraint only at EF level you should use the fluent API:

```
public class testEF : DbContext {
    public IDbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeEFConfiguration());
    }
}

public class EmployeeEFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee> {
    public EmployeeEFConfiguration() {
        HasRequired(x => x.Dep).WithMany(y => y.Employees);
    }
}
```

I just made the test. Previous code runs. If I use the RequiredAttribute, I had the same exception as you.

full sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Linq;

namespace testEf6 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (testEF ctx = new testEF()) {
                C2 c2 = new C2 {
                    Name = "old name",
                    C1 = new C1 { }
                };

                ctx.C2s.Add(c2);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (testEF ctx = new testEF()) {
                C2 c2 = ctx.C2s.First();
                c2.Name = "new name";
                ctx.SaveChanges(); // exception here with the attribute ========
            }
        }
    }

    public class testEF : DbContext {
        public IDbSet<C2> C2s { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new C2EFConfiguration());
        }
    }

    public class C2EFConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<C2> {
        public C2EFConfiguration() {
            HasRequired(x => x.C1).WithMany(y => y.C2s);
        }
    }

    public class C1 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<C2> C2s { get; set; }
    }

    public class C2 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required] 
        public virtual C1 C1 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: The `Required` attribute! I overlooked that when I tried to reproduce this. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: `virtual` enables lazy loading, which simply means when you retrieve a record from database, its related entities will be brought as well. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Question 2:

Can you try this:

```
Employee employee = Repository.Employees.Include("Dep").Single(p => p.Id ==<some id>);
var entry = context.Entry(employee);
entry.Property(e => e.name ).IsModified = true;
// other changed properties
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This made my understanding of how to use the virtual better, and solves Question 1. But Question 2 is still a mystery. Setting EntityState.Modified makes no difference,

Comment: Setting .Include("Dep") makes it work, the same way as if I makes it load by accessing the Dep in employee.dep.Id as mentioned above. But still I don't understand why I need to load Dep, when I only have changes to Employee that I want to save.

Comment: personally I do not use lazyloading and prefer 'Include()' for eager loading and I think eager loading provides more control. LazyLoading does some magic but that magic sometimes does not work the way we want.